# USB devices not detected unless clicked on scan for hard changes in device manager after enabling Virtual Machine Platform or Hyper-V in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, bsod, hyper-v

- CPU - AMD Ryzen 3 1200 (SVM is enabled)
- Windows - Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.264)
- USB Devices tried to connect - External Hard Disk, Pen Drives (All are USB3.0 ports)

Other Issues:

1. When I manually click on Scan for hardware changes, sometimes my system freezes and causes a **BSOD** named **dpc watchdog violation**
2. Keeping the hard disk connected makes the system very slow and unresponsive sometimes, there are no CPU spikes in task manager though

Had the same issue before in previous version of Windows 10, when enabling Hyper-V alone, I thought the newer build would fix those issues. But the issue still persists.

> **Updates**

1. Issue was occurring **even before 2004 upgrade**.
2. Issue occurring for a long time, but haven't found a proper solution (i thought 2004 version would fix these issues).
3. Even on a fresh windows 10 install, after enabling Hyper-V, I get this USB issues.
4. Just enabling the feature Hyper-V itself causes the USB issue (**Did not create any VM**)
5. I haven't added any new hardware since i bought the desktop back in Dec 2017 and haven't done any BIOS update
6. BIOS Name & Version - American Megatrends Inc 1.10, 24 Mar-17
7. Motherboard - MSI B350M Mortar (MS-7A37)
8. Updated to latest chipset drivers from (https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350M-MORTAR#down-driver&Win10%2064)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your BIOS of your motherboard? Might need to check there. Also, did you try some of these suggested fixes online?

- Tom's Hardware: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-fix-dpc-watchdog-violation-windows-10,36200.html
- Windows Report: https://windowsreport.com/dpc-watchdog-violation-windows-8/

You're already on a new build of Win 10 2004 so we can rule that out.

Additional questions:

- Did this happen before upgrading to 2004?
- How long has this been occurring?
- Any other major changes to your computer's software or hardware lately?

Also...

You mentioned enabling Hyper-V. Are you trying to connect a USB device through to a guest VM using Hyper-V? If so, then this below is relevant.

From a server admin perspective: I've had similar issues related to USB passthru from the physical host to the VM guest.

What I've found works much better and more reliably is to share the USB drive as a shared folder from the HOST OS to the guest. If these are workgroup devices and not a domain, you'll need to set up a user on both Hyper-V host and guest with the same password. Then allow this user to access that share. Then you can map a drive to the shared USB device from the host. Even though the mapped drive will appear as a network device, the performance is still as if the drive was direct attached to the guest.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your issue with using USB passthru, but I wanted to share my experience when I've done the same thing to server systems.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope i have clarified the questions you asked me.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Couple more questions: 1) Have you tried the latest chipset drivers from MSI? (https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350M-MORTAR#down-driver)      2) Have you tried unplugging the USB port connector cable that is inside your case? Could be the connector needs to be unplugged and replugged - also remove dust from the connector and pins if there is any...

Comment: 1. Yes I have updated all the drivers to the latest, I also used https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php and updated the outdated drivers using that (issue still persists after updating drivers as well) . 2. If dust and improper plugging was the issue, the usb issue should occur even without enabling the windows features right ?

Comment: Ah, yeah that is a good point. I am also a fan of driver booster and find it very useful to get all the other drivers up to date... Since you're only seeing the problem with when enabling Hyper-V, perhaps it is a driver compatibility bug between MSI and Microsoft. I'll let you know if I hear anything about it from other sys admins I work with.