# Desktop won't start and shows CPU EZ debug LED solid red light after enabling SVM

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

After enabling Secure Virtual Machine (SVM), my pc doesn't boot and shows solid red light on the CPU EZ debug LED.
I recently updated my BIOS to the latest version (**7A37v1MV** Beta version).

I have no issues if i **disable the SVM**, pc boots smoothly.

**NOTE:** I have all the setting in the BIOS to default except (enabled SVM), which is disabled by default.

> CPU: AMD Ryzen 1200

> Motherboard: [MSI B350M Mortar](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350M-MORTAR.html)

Comment: Beta versions could have bugs.

Comment: @Moab I upgraded to this bios because, i was planning to update to the 3rd gen cpu, even before that I had issues with SVM, which i have covered in another question and some of them suggested to upgrade the BIOS.

https://superuser.com/questions/1558052/usb-devices-not-detected-unless-clicked-on-scan-for-hard-changes-in-device-manag

Comment: I do not have a clear idea whether is the problem with the motherboard or the cpu.